# How to access keys inside my Redis cloud database?

Tags: redis, redislabs

I've created a Redis database on the Redis cloud with AWS. Till now I've added 5 hashes(key-value pairs) to the database but I can't seem to find a way to view those hashes. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect using the command line `redis-cli` and the host, port and password for your Redis instance, then use the command `hgetall <keyname>` to see the contents of the hash stored at `<keyname>`.

Alternatively, download a copy of the graphical [RedisInsight](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/) tool, and connect that to the host, port and password you're running Redis on.

Comment: Thanks, Simon Prickett I connected to my redislabs database with the help of redis-CLI. It required some research but was definitely worth the time. Thanks again for taking out the time to reply. :-)